# How to check the kind of a NSRange variable

Tags: objective-c

I have a variable that is passed as id and I would like to check if its type is NSRange but I can't use `[var isKindOfClass:[NSRange class]]` because NSRange is not a class. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` means a pointer to an object of some sort. Hence it cannot possibly be an `NSRange`.

It's possible your object is an `NSRange` wrapped in an `NSValue` object, in which case you can do the following to unwrap it:

```
if ([var isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]])
{
    NSValue *value = (NSValue *)var;
    NSRange range = [value rangeValue];
    // use range
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with johnpatrickmorgan's response but the following might be faster

```
if([var respondsToSelector:@selector(rangeValue)])
{
    NSRange range = [var rangeValue];
}
```